# Properly set textscan returns empty cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file in the format of:

```
123123  4
123234  4
515511  4
157888  4
854634  4
345661  4
```

I want to be able to import each column into a different variable. I've tried:

```
data = textscan(fid, '%f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);   
test = textscan(fid, '%*f %f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);
```

Which successfully imports the first column of numbers however `test` returns `[]`.

What is causing this?

Comment: Why not use the simpler form - `textscan(fid,'%f %f','HeaderLines',0)`?

Comment: I have also tried that - the second column ends up populated with 0's after cell2mat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you're scanning the whole file **two times** - that's not a good idea.

---

So how about [**importing**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) everything in one variable and splitting it up afterwards?

```
DATA = importdata('myFile.txt',' ',0)

data = DATA(:,1);
test = DATA(:,2);

clear DATA
```

Be aware that if you have headerlines, the code varies a little:

```
headerlines = 5
DATA = importdata('myData.txt',' ',headerlines)

data = DATA.data(:,1);
test = DATA.data(:,2);
```

If the white space delimiter `' '` is not working, try tabulator `'/t'`.

---

The reason why your approach is not working is the file-ID `fid`. Imagine `fid` is a pack of tasty cheese. Every line of the file which got read by textscan is like you have eaten one slice of cheese. So after your command:

```
data = textscan(fid, '%f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);
```

there is no cheese left. And your second `textscan` call is left without any cheese. To make it work you would need to open another similar pack of cheese:

```
fid = fopen('myData.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f %*f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);   
fclose(fid)

fid = fopen('myData.txt');
test = textscan(fid, '%*f %f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);
fclose(fid)
```

But I tell you, you will get fat. But if you really want to eat cheese, do it as follows:

```
fid = fopen('myData.txt');
DATA = textscan(fid, '%f %f %*[^\n]','HeaderLines',0);   
fclose(fid)

data = DATA(1);
test = DATA(2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was mostly curious as to why the above method was not working. Perhaps there is something wrong with my .txt file.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann: I finally got the time to give you the reason for your code not working. Have a look at my edit.