# find and match multiple values in the same row in array in matlab

Tags: matlab, find, row

I have a data set consists of the following (which are head values for a finite difference groundwater flow model consists of 200 row, 200 column, and 5 layers)

```
, "id", "k", "i", "j", "f", "Active"
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 313, 0
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 315.2.0, 0
3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 301.24, 0
4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 306.05, 0
5, 5, 1, 1, 5, -999.0, 0
6, 6, 1, 1, 6, -999.0, 0
7, 7, 1, 1, 7, 310.57, 0
8, 8, 1, 1, 8, -999.0, 0
9, 9, 1, 1, 9, -999.0, 0
.
.
.
200000, 200000, 5, 200, 200, -999.0, 0
```

let us assume that I need to find the row that has a specific i,j,k

 for example I want to find the row which has i=100, j=50, k=3 to store the value `f` for multiple i,j,k

 I've tried to use `find` but it finds only the location for a specific item

 I know it can be done using `for & if` but it will be time demanding 

 Is there a fast way to do so using matlab?

Comment: Are you reading the dataset from a text file ?

Comment: @Umar yes the data set is stored in text file

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your text file has the following data

```
"id", "k", "i", "j", "f", "Active"
1, 1, 1, 1, 313, 0
2, 1, 1, 2, 315.2.0, 0
3, 1, 1, 3, 301.24, 0
4, 1, 1, 4, 306.05, 0
5, 1, 1, 5, -999.0, 0
6, 1, 1, 6, -999.0, 0
7, 1, 1, 7, 310.57, 0
8, 1, 1, 8, -999.0, 0
9, 1, 1, 9, -999.0, 0
```

First read the file through

```
>> fileID = fopen('testfileaccess.txt');
>> C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s','Delimiter',',')
```

You will get 6 cells representing each column

```
C = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}

  Column 6

    {10x1 cell}

>> Matrix= [str2double(C{2}).';str2double(C{3}).';str2double(C{4}).';].'
```

the above code will result the i j and k in a matrix with each row representing each variable

```
Matrix =

   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     1     4
     1     1     5
     1     1     6
     1     1     7
     1     1     8
     1     1     9
```

then if you want to find for example k = 1 , i = 1 and j = 8 you use `find()`

```
find(Matrix(:,1) == 1 & Matrix(:,2) == 1 & Matrix(:,3) == 8)
```

and there you have it

```
ans =

     8
```

8th row

Comment: this is not working as in `C` matrix generates a blank line separator after each value

Comment: Well write the whole code in a script , if you open the file and run  ('C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s','Delimiter',',') ')the first time the C will access the data but the second time it will be an empty matrix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797572/properly-set-textscan-returns-empty-cell-array refer to this question

Answer (score 0):

```
row = jcount*kcount*(i-1) + kcount*(j-1) + k
```

In your case:

```
row = 200*5*(i-1) + 5*(j-1) + k
```